# Reducing build size of spring boot application while using aws s3 sdk dependency

Tags: spring, spring-boot, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am using a aws sdk in my spring boot application for file upload but it is making my build heavy whose size is near about 145mb to 150mb.

I am just doing file upload on s3 bucket in my application.

How can i reduce my war size.

Here is my aws dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.510</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot of dependencies are just added based on dependency tree, in case you are not using the feature, better you remove them one by one. See [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=97UTDmonq7w) which will help you in identifying unused dependency.

Comment: Please mention which part of this video shows how we can indentify the unused dependency.